# Jasperserver Domain based report - how can input control be applied

Tags: jasperserver

We are working with domains on Jasperserver (not using Jasperstudio). When we create an ad-hoc-report and then create a report out of that we can edit the report's properties.

Within those properties we can define an input control. Since the report is defined on a domain we do also define the input control on the domain. Now, when we run the report the input control shows up as requested and it has a list of the requested values. So far so good. But when the input control's selected value is applied the report is not filtered by that value but does simply show all values. We have turned on query logging and it's obvious from there that there is no effort to apply a filter.

Isn't it possible to get this running by using Jasperserver's web interface only?

When we define the report in Studio and create a connection to the input control (which hss been defined on the web interface only), then the report filters as suggested but we miss the comfort of the web interface.

Comment: I think it would be better if you put an screenshot or something similar..I have just been working in the same way and sometimes I felt it is not very intuitive..
Maybe, it is only at the beginning..

Comment: I thought about this, but there is not really a creative way. We work solely on the web interface of JasperServer pro (5.6) and use a domain. There is not much to do wrong on the report creation. If we apply a filter, then the report is fine, if we create an input control that results in the same attribute than the report is not filtered by this attribute. Actually we could ignore that and go on with a filter, but we want to build cascading input controls and so we must get that working this way.